# why My table view is automatically scrolling to bottom after reloading data- Xcode 9 , iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview, xcode9

I have a table view and I am reloading the data in a particular interval. my issue is -- if reloading happens when the table is at top no problem, but if the table is in middle position it automatically scrolling to bottom ,Could you please help me to fix this ? **Xcode 9**, **ios 11**

I am using [_myTableView reloadData] for reloading

Comment: Please show your code for better response. Would be better if you can edit your question & paste your reload code.

Comment: [_dashBoardTableView reloadData];

Comment: No in that question , the want to scroll to bottom , my table is automatically scrolling to bottom i don't want to go to bottom automatically

Comment: please show your code for better response.....

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code. So that we can find out why it tableview scrolls to bottom. This is unusual behavior.

Comment: Possible cause for your problem: if the number of cells are more before the reloadData method, and their number is reduced afterwards. So it might looks like the tableView is scrolling when in fact it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my God , I finally fixed the issue. i have the table view with different height cells for each section , So when i given the estimated height and also provided the specific height for each cell.

I think the table view is ambiguous about your cell size height , that is why its reloading the cells and scrolling to bottom.